# App crashes on lumia 520

Tags: lumia-520, instagram

I am using lumia 520 and face a new problem after I update instagram

When I open instagram, No issues with photos but when I scroll to video It crashes. So what will be the issue ?

I think its problem with coding of App?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using the official Instagram app? Have you tried alternative apps like 6tag? Does this problem also happen in other apps like Facebook or Twitter (assuming you use those)?

Comment: Yes, I am using official instagram app and there is no problem into facebook and twitter. I dont tries those alternatives

Comment: Is this the Instagram Beta app, or the replacement Instagram app?

Comment: @RowlandShaw it is instagram beta app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Instagram Beta app that had this bug was replaced by a newer Instagram app; however, it is listed as a separate app in the store, so you will need to install the [later app](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/instagram/9nblggh5l9xt) separately

Comment: The new Instagram app is for Windows 10 only, though. If the OP is running WP8.1 (seems probable given they're using a Lumia 520), I'd recommend [6tag](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrfhvxc) instead.